# Consulta funciona no MySQL, mas não no Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Eu rodo uma consulta no `MySQL` que funciona e no `Laravel` não, segue

***SQL***:

```
select resource_id as "pedido", count(resource_id) as "perguntas",
       date_received from perguntas_pos where status="UNANSWERED" 
group by 1 order by 2 desc
```

e quando rodo no `Laravel` diz o seguinte ***erro***:

> `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'pergunta_ml.perguntas_pos.date_received' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select resource_id as "pedido", count(resource_id) as "perguntas", date_received from perguntas_pos where status="UNANSWERED" group by 1 order by 2 desc)`

Por que eu tenho que colocar o `date_received` no `GROUP BY` também?

Comment: Eu acho que um dos problemas é o uso de aspas em: `...as "pedido"` e `...as "perguntas"`. Tente primeiro remover essas aspas.

Comment: Paulo, fiz a alteração e não são as aspas.

Comment: Para utilizar o `GROUP BY`, você deve especificar colunas e não números. Dá uma olhada nesse link: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: Pode mostrar seu código no laravel que está executando também?

Comment: Coloque o código que você fez no Laravel!

Comment: class PedidosController extends Controller {

 public function pedidos() {
  $pedidos = DB::select('select resource_id, count(resource_id) as perguntas, date_received from perguntas_pos where status="UNANSWERED" group by 1 order by 2 desc');
  return view('pedidos.pedidos')-> with('pedidos', $pedidos);
 }